# A Perfectly good Substring Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, substring

Im having a problem parsing a string array of Directories. The end goal is to query the path tied to the [global].MyDataDir & "\saved" to get all folders in this directory. However the actual foldernames, the last bit of text after the last indexof "\" holds the name of a plugin that I need to compare against an enumerated list of plugins for further functionality I won't get into here. The problem here is my last bit of code wont work. The Dim foldername as String = (etc...), It returns an error saying Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length.

Can any of you wizards, help me out here. Much appreciated.

```
Dim dirList As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories([global].MyDataDir & "\saved")
For dir As Integer = 0 To dirList.Length - 1
    If IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirList(dir)).Length > 0 Then
        For Each file As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirList(dir))

            Dim folderName As String = dirList(dir).ToString.Substring(dirList(dir).ToString.LastIndexOf("\"), dirList(dir).ToString.Length - 1)

        Next
    End If
Next
```

Semper Fi.

Comment: Have you tried using Debug.Print to output the values of dirList(dir).ToString.LastIndexOf("\") and dirList(dir).ToString.Length - 1, as well as the value of dirList(dir).ToString?  If you have (or if you can, please) what's their output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName() instead.

Next time use the VB.NET Left() convenience function to avoid getting this wrong.

Comment: Oh, duh.  My brain, it is not switched on right now, hence why I even asked the questions in my above comment.  +1 to you, sir.

Comment: Nice you guys are great. Never have even run into the Left() function yet. Always up for learning better, faster, ways of doing things. Thanks again to all of you. May the force be with you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason....

The problem lies in the arguments of Substring(starting index, length of copy from starting index). I was under the impression, the length argument would take into account the entire string when calculating the length. Instead the second argument of this function acts upon the results of the first argument, not the entire string. So the length of the string is actually much longer than what exists after taking an index of it.

Thanks for the help.